# replace character to number in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have function `change` which replace some characters to numbers. Here it is:

```
change [] = []
change (x:xs) | x == 'A'  = '9':'9':change xs
              | x == 'B'  = '9':'8':change xs
              | otherwise = change xs
```

and the output is:

```
Main> change "aAB11s"
"9998"
```

but I need this:

```
Main> change "aAB11s"
"a999811s"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: your otherwise clause is losing the x. I'm not very familiar with Haskell but you probably want `otherwise = x : change cs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @kostya 's answer, you don't need to write the recursive part youself, try this out:

```
change :: String -> String
change xs = concatMap chToStr xs
    where chToStr 'A' = "99"
          chToStr 'B' = "98"
          chToStr  x =  [x]
```

or, more [point-freely](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree) (actually this is preferred if the point-free refactoring doesn't hurt the readability):

```
change :: String -> String
change = concatMap chToStr
    where chToStr 'A' = "99"
          chToStr 'B' = "98"
          chToStr  x  = [x]
```

And you can test the result:

```
λ> change "aAB11s"
"a999811s"
```

Some explanation:

It's tempting to do an elementwise replacement by passing `map` a function 
`f :: Char -> Char`. But here you can't do that because for `A`, you want two characters, i.e. `99`, so the function you want is of type `Char -> String` (`String` and `[Char]` in Haskell are equivalent) which does not fit the type signature.

So the solution is to also wrap other characters we don't care about into lists, and afterwards, we can perform a [string concatenation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation)(this function in Haskell is called [concat](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3aconcat)) to get a string back.

Further, `concatMap f xs` is just a shorthand for `concat (map f xs)`

```
λ> map (\x -> [x,x]) [1..10]
[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5],[6,6],[7,7],[8,8],[9,9],[10,10]]
λ> concat (map (\x -> [x,x]) [1..10])
[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10]
λ> concatMap (\x -> [x,x]) [1..10]
[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10]
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
change [] = []
change (x:xs) | x == 'A'  = '9':'9':change xs
              | x == 'B'  = '9':'8':change xs
              | otherwise = x:change xs
```

The only change is in otherwise.